# FIND: Parameter format not correct when piping ping command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find, cygwin

I am trying to get the response of a ping test onto a json file.

```
set RESPONSE=$(ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 | find "time=")
echo %RESPONSE% >> results.json
```

When I try ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 | find "time=" on cmd prompt directly it works fine. But when I run this in a script, I get the following error:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

Does anyone know why? many thanks.

Comment: You can't do that. Type `for /?` on how to parse command output.

Comment: Well, not sure how you expect it to be in json form, but you could `(ping %ipaddress% | find "time=")>results.json`

Comment: @Mark thank you, the for /f function worked for me.

Comment: @Gerhard, json form is achieved as long as I follow the {"":"","":""} format right?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this issue thanks to Mark's advice of using for.

```
FOR /F "skip=7 tokens=9" %%G IN ('ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1') DO set REPONSE=%%G
echo "reponse time": "%REPONSE%", >>  results.json
```

did it for me. (I'm pretty sure it's bad coding though, I was playing with the positions of the words, so if the ping command output ever changes, my code stops working.)

Comment: I would take the average instead. `for /F "tokens=6" %G IN ('ping google.com -n 1 ^| find "Average"') DO set REPONSE=%%G`

Comment: The purpose of `For` variables is to use them - not assign them to another variable. CMD has three types of variables for three different purposes.

Comment: @Gerhard I think what my skip 7 does is what your find average does. The line with the keyword "Average" is on line 8, word 9. What does the ^ do by the way?

Comment: @Mark yes, I am using the for loop. I dropped the set RESPONSE at the beginning and moved it inside the loop.

Comment: @punpun123 `for` respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file starts in background `%ComSpec% /c`  and the command line within `'`  appended as additional arguments. So to run in background `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ping google.com -n 1 | find "Average"` it is necessary to escape the character `|` with `^` to be interpreted as literal character for `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. Otherwise the `for` command line with `|` not inside a double quoted argument string would result in a syntax error message and an exit of batch file processing by `cmd.exe` parsing `for` command line.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood your question, I have a feeling that you're actually wanting your `results.json` to hold the line `$(ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 | find "time=")`, *obviously with `%IPADDRESS%` expanded to its value*. For that you'd probably be best advised to use delayed expansion, like this:

```batch-file
Set "RESPONSE=$(ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 | find "time=")"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(Echo !RESPONSE!) 1>> "results.json" 
EndLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get a JSON file would be:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Test-Connection -ComputerName localhost -Count 1 |" ^
        "Select-Object -Property ResponseTime |" ^
        "ConvertTo-Json |" ^
        "Out-File -FilePath 'C:\src\t\results.json' -Encoding ascii"
```

This produces:

```
{
    "ResponseTime":  0
}
```

If the system is running pwsh, the following can be used.

```
PS C:\> Test-Connection -ComputerName www.ibm.com -Count 1 |
    Select-Object -Property Latency |
    ConvertTo-Json
{
  "Latency": 38
}
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.0.1
```